# Smartphone Browser break SVG image

Tags: html, css, svg

So i have this SVG image on my site. Which works perfectly on desktop. But on smartphones it is an entirely different story[image: image of fail]

As you can see it breaks up the image. But it only does that on smartphones.

Any idea why?
Its just a normal img tag:

```
<img src="brand.svg">
```

EDIT!!

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320.65 66.28">
    <defs>
    <style>
    .cls-1{
    font-size:50px;
    }
    .cls-1,.cls-4{
    font-family:Montserrat-SemiBold, Montserrat;font-weight:700;
    }
    .cls-2{
    letter-spacing:0em;
    }
    .cls-3{
    letter-spacing:-0.01em;
    }
    .cls-4{
    font-size:16px;
    }
    .cls-5{
    letter-spacing:-0.02em;
    }
    .cls-6{
    letter-spacing:0em;
    }
    .cls-7{
    letter-spacing:0em;
    }
    .cls-8{
    letter-spacing:0.01em;
    }
    </style>
    </defs>
    <title>Aktiv 3</title>
    <g id="Lag_2" data-name="Lag 2">
    <g id="Lag_1-2" data-name="Lag 1">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(0 42.5)">Designpl<tspan class="cls-2" x="230.3" y="0">a</tspan>
    <tspan class="cls-3" x="260.9" y="0">c</tspan>
    <tspan x="289.55" y="0">e</tspan></text>
    <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(0.35 62.04)">A <tspan class="cls-5" x="16.4" y="0">w</tspan>
    <tspan class="cls-6" x="30.86" y="0">o</tspan>
    <tspan class="cls-7" x="41.18" y="0">r</tspan>
    <tspan x="47.82" y="0">k of A</tspan>
    <tspan class="cls-8" x="95.04" y="0">r</tspan>
    <tspan class="cls-6" x="102" y="0">t</tspan>
    </text>
    </g>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

I can see in the code that there are sometimes some spans, with only 1 letter. Can that be it? The weird thing is that it works on desktops and laptops perfectly.

EDIT!!
[image: Working example]

WORKING!
I got it to work. i cleaned up the code by writing how it really should look (deleted spaces, deleted the tspans, and deleted the x and y cordinates) then i imported using another name. Because the smartphones that i was testing it on didn't want to reload using: Javascript:location.reload(true).

Comment: Post the SVG code, please.

Comment: Looks like a funky SVG, the width is trying to go wider but the letters not scaling evenly... share the code inside `brand.svg` file.

Comment: You need to post the SVG code for us to help, but it may be the SVG uses <text> elements set to a “font-family” that’s missing on the mobile devices you tested.

Comment: I added the code know. I see some spans in the code where there is only 1 letter, but the weird is that it word on desktop perfectly.

Comment: We need a [mcve] so we can see it go wrong. E.g. one of the CSS rules might also impact how the SVG render.

Comment: @LGSon I can say that even with a blank page, it does the same thing. i Edited the code, so it is easier to read

Comment: For me it looks the same on desktop, hence we need a _verifiable sample_. And of course the `tspan` creates that space.

Comment: @LGSon I've added a working example from my laptop.

Comment: That is a screen dump. How do you think we should debug the _"code"_ behind it? Please reread [ask].

Comment: the problem is what code should i give? i have given a working code that works on my pc... i have tried to remove the tspan, but that dosen't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `x` and `y` attributes from the `<tspan>`s and the spaces between the `<tspan>`s

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320.65 66.28">
<defs>
<style>
.cls-1{
font-size:50px;
}
.cls-1,.cls-4{
font-family:Montserrat-SemiBold, Montserrat;font-weight:700;
}
.cls-2{
letter-spacing:0em;
}
.cls-3{
letter-spacing:-0.01em;
}
.cls-4{
font-size:16px;
}
.cls-5{
letter-spacing:-0.02em;
}
.cls-6{
letter-spacing:0em;
}
.cls-7{
letter-spacing:0em;
}
.cls-8{
letter-spacing:0.01em;
}
</style>
</defs>
<title>Aktiv 3</title>
<g id="Lag_2" data-name="Lag 2">
<g id="Lag_1-2" data-name="Lag 1">
<text class="cls-1" transform="translate(0 42.5)">Designpl<tspan class="cls-2" >a</tspan><!--
--><tspan class="cls-3" >c</tspan><!--
--><tspan>e</tspan></text>
  
  
<text class="cls-4" transform="translate(0.35 62.04)">A <tspan class="cls-5" x="16.4" y="0">w</tspan><!--
--><tspan class="cls-6">o</tspan><!--
--><tspan class="cls-7">r</tspan><!--
--><tspan>k of A</tspan><!--
--><tspan class="cls-8" >r</tspan><!--
--><tspan class="cls-6" >t</tspan>
</text>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Okay it seems that it is working somewhat, if i put it in a codepen, it works. but it seems like ssmartphones cant refresh the cache on my site

Comment: Change the file's name

Comment: GOT IT. I cleaned up the code and change the name. Thx